# Expression for straight male who prefers the company of gay men

Tags: expressions, terminology, slang, sexual-minorities

We used to call women who preferred the company of gay men as

> ["fag hags"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fag_hag)

What are straight men who prefer the company of gay men called? I found nothing on the internet, unless you count Urban.

Comment: Also taking the opportunity to create the tag "LGBTQ"

Comment: I'm guessing that any such expression would be highly dependent on your political leanings.

Comment: @HotLicks...interesting. Are you implying that there is  a difference in meaning or interpretation depending on political leaning?

Comment: Well, duh!!  Even a bland term such as "gay friendly" will be highly politicized by some parties.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not live in the US, although much of what happens there affects us a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comparison to the term "fag hag", I assume you want a term that could be used in similar contexts, regardless of whether some people might find the term tasteless or unpleasant ([some women find the term "fag hag" offensive](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/thumbs-up-for-girls-who-l_b_794266), and I assume the terms I list below could also cause offense).

I think "fag hag" is more frequent than any term that specifically refers to a man. So I think the most obvious way to express the idea would just be "male fag hag", which has a number of hits on Google.

When I searched for that phrase, I also found the following terms...

### fruit fly

Using Google, I found a couple sources that give the term "**fruit fly**". It seems to be a similar term that doesn't have to refer to a man, but that could be used to refer to a man.

- *[Beethoven's Kiss: Pianism, Perversion, and the Mastery of Desire](https://books.google.com/books?id=BmU91PWywEQC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=%22fruit%20fly%22),* by Kevin Kopelson, p. 147
- [`andybent25`](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaybros/comments/s8kvv/what_do_you_call_a_bro_version_of_a_fag_hag/c4c1vhe/), Fri Apr 13 2012 19:27:30 GMT-0700, in Reddit thread "What do you call a bro version of a fag hag?"
- > See, this is why I like the term "fruit fly." I refer to my female hang out buds as fruit flies. Don't know if Lesbians mind being referred to as fruits or not, but the term could work for anybody, I guess. Heh. I've got straight male buds who I've told hangin' round with me makes them fruit flies.

  "Post #15 02-24-2005, 05:07 PM by `swampbear` in "Male Equivalent of a Fag Hag?" Straight Dope Message Board

  *The thread is about a term for men who prefer the company of lesbians, but the context implies that swampbear is a gay man who uses the term "fruit fly" to refer to people, male or female, who like to hang out with gay men (or women).*
- > I am a Fruit Fly, for sure! Honestly, except for 2 of them, every man I've been friends with or romatically interested in have been gay! It became quite depressing until my boyfriend came along. [...] I guess I'm a gay man trapped in a woman's body.

  "[Are you a "fag hag"?](https://prince.org/msg/100/205515)", Post #6 10/16/06 11:02am by `UCantHavaDaMango` in thread on prince.org forums

### stag hag, fag stag

There are also some people who replace either "fag" or "hag" with "stag" in order to imply a specifically male equivalent.

#### fag stag

- > Canonically 'fag stag' is the term for a straight guy who hangs out with mostly gay dudes.

  [`kspacey`](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaybros/comments/s8kvv/what_do_you_call_a_bro_version_of_a_fag_hag/c4bz8mv/), Fri Apr 13 2012 15:20:05 GMT-0700, in Reddit thread "What do you call a bro version of a fag hag?"
- Post #3 02-24-2005, 10:58 AM by `lisacurl` in "Male Equivalent of a Fag Hag?", Straight Dope Message Board

#### stag hag

- > a male 'fag hag' is a 'Stag Hag'

  [`iRedEarth`](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaybros/comments/s8kvv/what_do_you_call_a_bro_version_of_a_fag_hag/c4ca5za/), Sat Apr 14 2012 13:37:16 GMT-0700, in Reddit thread "What do you call a bro version of a fag hag?"

### Threads on this topic (quoted above)

- "[Male Equivalent of a Fag Hag?](https://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=304088)", Straight Dope Message Board, first post 02-24-2005, 10:52 AM by plnnr
- "[What do you call a bro version of a fag hag?](https://www.reddit.com/r/gaybros/comments/s8kvv/what_do_you_call_a_bro_version_of_a_fag_hag)", Reddit, r/gaybros, first post Fri Apr 13 2012 14:32:11 GMT-0700, by `honoraryorange`

Comment: @Cascabel: I linked in the first para to an article that talks about it. Although it doesn't go into detail, it has the following explanation: "Straight women who have rejected the label “fag hag” argue that lying at the etymological root of this moniker are misogynistic stereotypes. And they feel that the term is not only derogatory about them, but that the term also demeans and distorts their rich relationships with their BFFs. But there are many other women who have also lovingly embraced the term." ("Thumbs up for “Girls Who Like Boys Who Like Boys”", by Irene Monroe, Huffpost 12/09/2010)

Comment: OMG...seriously, this politically correct stuff must stop somewhere. From what I remember from NYC in the 70s and 80s, women had no objection to embracing the term. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I like _fag stag_. I’ll have to start using that if ever I come across someone who’d fit the bill. @Cascabel I can understand why a woman would find it offensive to be called any kind of hag – especially a type that also uses what remains a very derogatory term for their friends. I do think most women (and gay men) own it, though.